# Are there any database implementations which keep all history?

Tags: database, version-control

Using a version control system for your source code (like [subversion](http://svn.tigris.org)) makes sense because it allows you to back out of mistakes, audit changes, make painless snapshots, discover exactly where something went wrong so that you can improve your process etc. For the same reasons it makes sense to do change tracking of **business data**, and many systems do so.

There are already a few questions on how to implement this on top of a normal database:

- [Database structure to track change
  history](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/141612/database-structure-to-track-change-history)
- [Maintain history in a database](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/739623/maintain-history-in-a-database)
- [Database history for client
  usage](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/655430/database-history-for-client-usage)
- [How to version control a record in a
  database](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/323065/323109#323109)
- ...

For a feature that is so useful and popular, it seems strange that we all need to reinvent the wheel. **Are there any existing database implementations which already solved this problem?** I'm imagining that such a system would extend the SQL syntax to allow easy querying of the history.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Take a look at [temporal databases](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Temporal_database), such as [TimeDB](http://www.timeconsult.com/Software/Software.html).

Comment: +1 for putting a name on the concept so that I can finally get some relevant google hits :-)

Answer (score 2):

Not a relational database (you didn't say it had to be), but [CouchDB](http://couchdb.apache.org/) has versioning built-in.

Comment: +1 interesting. A very fresh approach to the whole problem of storing and querying data.

Answer (score 1):

The space requirements would be prohibitive, so this is why you typically roll your own.

There are different solutions, depending on your toolkit:

- [Hibernate EnVers](http://www.jboss.org/envers/) for plugging in Hibernate;
- [HBase](http://hadoop.apache.org/hbase/) has limited versioning built-in;

Comment: This doesn't make sense.  Yes, such databases are inherently bulky.  Why does that mean you should roll your own, though?

Comment: Roll your own - implement it yourself.

Comment: I know what roll your own means.  The question is why.

Comment: @Matthew Flaschen - I misread your question, sorry. I meant to say that in my opinion this is a situation where it's too difficult to specify exactly what/how/for how long/where to archive so there is no general implementation available, therefore the solutions are custom-made.

Answer (score 0):

As far as the data goes, I believe it's called ["change data capture](http://www.google.com/search?rlz=1C1GGLS_enUS291US323&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8&q=change+data+capture+relational+database)".

Answer (score -1):

Given that most countries require that all accounting transactions are logged, pretty well every database lets you record the history for auditing.

Comment: I'm looking for "lets you query the history", not "lets you record the history".

Comment: If your original schema has time stamps, it's not a problem.
If your original schema does not, load the history adding them.